# How to wait for promise to complete in another class

Tags: php, guzzle6, guzzle

In another class, I have a [promise](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html) which works ok. I need to use the returned data in another controller but I do not know how to wait for the data in the other controller:

```php
class PromiseController
{
  private function load()
  {
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    // variables omitted for example
    $promise = $client->requestAsync('POST', $url, $options);
    $json = null;
    $promise->then(
        function (ResponseInterface $res) {
            $xml = simplexml_load_string($res->getBody(),'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);
            $json = json_encode($xml);
            $json = $json;
            // I see my json here. Great.
        },
        function (RequestException $e) {
            Log::info($e->getMessage());
            echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
            echo $e->getRequest()->getMethod();
        }
    );

    $return $json;
  }
}
```

The controller where the data is needed:

```php
// Leaving out the function etc

$data = ( new PromiseController )->load();

return array(

  'xmlAsJson' => $data

);
```

The returned data always `null`. I need to wait for the data in the "needed" controller but how? I want to have a separate controller to process the xml to json before passing the result to the `array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to propagate async, you have to continue with promises, so return a new promise from your controller:

```
class PromiseController
{
    private function load()
    {
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $promise = $client->requestAsync('POST', $url, $options);
        $jsonPromise = $promise->then(
            function (ResponseInterface $res) {
                $xml = simplexml_load_string($res->getBody(),'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);
                $json = json_encode($xml);

                return $json;
            },
            function (RequestException $e) {
                Log::info($e->getMessage());
                echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
                echo $e->getRequest()->getMethod();
            }
        );

        return $jsonPromise;
  }
}
```

And call `->wait()` on the resulting promise in the code later:

```
$data = ( new PromiseController )->load()->wait();

return array(
    'xmlAsJson' => $data
);
```

Comment: Awesome, dude!!